# System keeps remembering the vote to undelete done from the users who wrote an answer even after the answer was undeleted

Tags: bug, answers, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

For the users who can see deleted questions on Drupal Answers, I am referring to an answer for https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185311/how-can-i-use-jquery-or-javascript-in-view. In short:

- A user answered the question, deleted his answer, and then undeleted it
- The question was closed by me
- 2 days ago, the question was automatically deleted

> [image: screenshot]

Now, that answer shows a cast vote to undeleted it, and that the answer has been only deleted by the owner.

> [image: screenshot]

What the [revisions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/185315/revisions) say is that the owner deleted the answer, undeleted it, and edited it.

> [image: screenshot]
>
> [image: screenshot]

Notice also that *deleted by the owner 2 days ago* is false, since the answer was automatically deleted from the system 2 days ago.

Comment: Huh, that's really strange. Also considering you can't vote to undelete the answer to deleted questions.

Comment: LOL you've duped yourself. Yuh, 4 years passed...